# Python/Pandas Isolating date range from dataframe and verifying it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

my objective is to extract the date range, written as 01 Jan 2017 - 05 Dec 2018, from a DataFrame and verify it against today's date. I am trying to use regex to find the date range because the dates inputted are always changing. Currently my code outputs the date as a list of dataframes, and ideally i would like my code to simply go through the dataframe, find the date range and save the two as separate variables.

```
    Old/New | Platform | other columns
      New       Random
      New       Words
      Timeframe for range 01 Jan 2017 - 05 Dec 2018
```

The timerange may not always be under the Old/New column.

So far I have the following:

```
beginning = [NB_LCP_parameters_2C17[col].str.extract(r'.*–\s?(.*$)',expand=True) for col in NB_LCP_parameters_2C17]    
end = [NB_LCP_parameters_2C17[col].str.extract(r'.*–\s?(.*$)',expand=True) for col in NB_LCP_parameters_2C17]
```

I am open to any alternatives to achieve my goal, but this is the method I have been toying with.

Comment: @ScottBoston I will edit my original post to include it